# Machine learning how to use the Facebook interest of a users to give a decision

Tags: machine-learning

I'm trying to figure out a way I could represent a Facebook user as a vector. I decided to go with stacking the different attributes/parameters of the user into one big vector (i.e. age is a vector of size 100, where 100 is the maximum age you can have, if you are lets say 50, the first 50 values of the vector would be 1 just like a thermometer). I just can't figure out a way to represent the Facebook interests as a vector too, they are a collection of words and the space that represents all the words is huge, I can't go for a model like a bag of words or something similar. Does anyone know how I should proceed? I'm still new to this, any reference would be highly appreciated.

In the case of a desire to down vote this question just let me know what is wrong about it so  that I could improve the wording and context.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "right" approach depends on what your learning algorithm is and what the decision problem is.

It would often be better, though, to represent age as a single numeric feature rather than 100 indicator features. That way learning algorithms don't have to learn the relationship between those hundred features (it's baked-in), and the problem has 99 fewer dimensions, which'll make everything better.

To model the interests, you might want to start with an extremely high-dimensional bag of words model and then use one of various options to reduce the dimensionality:

- a general dimensionality-reduction technique like [PCA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) or smarter nonlinear ones, including [Kernel PCA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_PCA) or various nonlinear approaches: see [wikipedia's overview of dimensionality reduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensionality_reduction) and of [specifically nonlinear techniques](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_dimensionality_reduction)
- pass it through a [topic model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topic_model) and use the learned topic weights as your features; examples include [LSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_semantic_analysis), [LDA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_Dirichlet_allocation), [HDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_Dirichlet_process) and many more